# how to retrieve a value of a cookie php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress installed and when a user logs in, it saves a cookie in the temporary files with the name of wordpress.

I want to retrieve the value of the cookie using php in another page (out of wordpress). What would be a method to retrieve a persistent cookie in php.

Comment: Do you want to get the current logged in user info out of wordpress?

Comment: If the cookie is not set to root domain will not be available out of wordpress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice three key value pairs on my local worpress installation. If you can place the php file under the same domain, then you can obtain the cookies as it appears worpress appropriately sets the cookie to "/". So for instance the key "wp-settings-1".

cookie_test.php

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["wp-settings-1"]))
{
    echo "Cookie: {$_COOKIE['wp-settings-1']}";
}
else
{
    echo "<h1>No Cookie Detected from wordpress!</h1>";

}
```

It has to be under the same domain. Locally I just drop this anywhere in the worpress folder and it will work when you browse to it.

Comment: I tried what you said and that didnt work either. its on local host under wordpress

Comment: @Autolycus what key are you using. I used "wp-settings-1" for mine. Do you have a web dev bar for your browser so you can easily inspect cookie names and values?

Answer (score 1):

Look in `$_COOKIE`.

However, keep in mind, that the path may be set different to where you want to read it.

Comment: @Aut: if that cookie path is set to `/wordpress` and you want them to access at `yourdomain.com/some_dir/page.php` the cookie will not accessible here

Answer (score 1):

You keep saying that its under localhost. But the point is, the cookie data wont be available between subdirectories of localhost. like the cookie set at `http://localhost/wordpress` wont be available at `http://localhost/drupal` .. you can only access the cookies of `http://localhost/wordpress` in that directory or subdirectories of it e.g. `http://localhost/wordpress/test-page` ..