# How do I read the value of a cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

How to retrieve the value of a cookie?

I m using the code:

```
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
```

But this gives me an error message:

> Undefined index: user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to retrieve a value of a cookie php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762685/how-to-retrieve-a-value-of-a-cookie-php)

Comment: this is because you dont have a cookie named `user`

Comment: Check if the user index is set in your cookie.  
print_r($_COOKIE);

Comment: your cookie not set or check your text case `User` `USER`

Answer (score 1):

[Before retrieving the cookie value you have to set the value:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

```
setcookie("user", "value");
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove undefined index error you should use `isset` with cookie retrieval. I hope you are using `setcookie` function to set the cookie.

like:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
       $user  = $_COOKIE['user'];
}
else
{
    //something else
}
```

docs: http://php.net/setcookie

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
    echo $_COOKIE["user"];
}
```